# How to select Report Design layout using AX code?

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've been modifying a Report design in AX. This design has three layouts, each layout has different sizes. So when the user wants to run the report and wants a specific size, he can just select a predefined size via a drop-down list and I will then use that as a parameter to call the the specific design layout.

My question is how can I call that specific design layout using AX code?

Note: this report is for the bar code labels.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us the name of the AOT report object?

Comment: its RetailLabel report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code in the `parmReportName` (AOT: `\Classes\RetailLabelController\parmReportName`).

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/srsreportruncontroller.parmreportname.aspx